# Estimation of standard error

Tags: self-study, standard-error

I was doing some self study and came across the following formulae for estimating standard errors:

**Formulae 1:**

[image]

**Formulae 2:**

[image]

I understand that these two can all be used when the Population Standard Deviation is unknown. But I don't really understand why one has that additional part at the back.

Appreciate some pointers please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first term is a biased estimation of the standard deviation, and the second is another estimate when the population you sample from is small, so your sample has a size comparable to the population. See details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) and references therein.

Comment: Thanks juampa. Am I right to say that the first is Biased and for generally larger population, while the second is unbiased and for small populations?

Comment: It is still biased. If you take the second estimate, and consider N to be much, much larger than n, then the factor is almost 1 and you are left with the same estimate. It is a correction to account for the fact that in that setting not all data from the finite population are observed.

Answer (score 1):

Used when sample is done with replacement from finite / infinite population

[image]

Used when sample is done without replacement from finite / infinite population

[image]

Comment: If you are interested in the derivation, you can have a look here (https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/264)